# How to create a JRDataSource with my Spring configuration dataSource?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I want to print a `Jasper` report , so there is the `JRDataSource` object to provide in the code :

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream, parameters, JRDataSourceObject);
```

In my Spring configuration class there is already a dataSource configured :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ambre.pta")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/admin.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/exercice.properties")
})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * méthode permettant d'accéder les fichiers de ressources tels que les langues
     * @return un gestionnaire de fichiers de ressources
     */
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    /**
     * méthode permettant de prÃ©ciser l'emplacement et l'extension des vues jsp
     * @return un gestionnaire de vue
     */
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * méthode permettant de spécifier la connexion à la base de données
     * @return un gestionnaire de connexion à  la base de données
     */
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.129:1521:xe");
        dataSource.setUsername("sse");
        dataSource.setPassword("sse");

        return dataSource;

    }

    ...
}
```

So how to create a `JRDataSource` from the Spring dataSource ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `JRDataSource` is basically used to fill the reports using data source objects. The data is loaded into data source objects.

Ref [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html).

> The engine expects to receive either a JRDataSource object as the data
>   source of the report that it has to fill, or a java.sql.Connection
>   when the report data is found in a relational database.
>
> As a
>   structured object, a data source object is more like a table with
>   columns and rows containing data in the table cells.

There are different implementations of `JRDataSource` interface. The examples can be seen [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html). You must choose the one that suits your need. We use `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` where the fields in the report are mapped to Java Bean objects